# access date for DB2 table

Tags: db2, mainframe

I am using the mainframe environment and need to find old tables which are not used / accessed before 2011. Are there any system tables to get the last accessed information from? DB2 VERSION: V10NF(DB2 Version 10 for z/OS).

Comment: If you are using a z series, rather than an i series, then should the ibm-midrange tag come off?

Comment: @WarrenT - I was hoping you would show up. Is DB2 different on z/OS from DB2 for i? I'm the one that added the `ibm-midrange` and `mainframe` tags in the hope that some folks more knowledgeable about IBM's "big iron" would show up and at least be able to point the OP in the right direction. From what little I know I don't think you can get this information via SQL unless some kind of auditing is enabled - and it's usually disabled for performance reasons.

Comment: @BennyHill There are 3 different DB2 platforms: IBM i, z/OS, and LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows). They support a large core of common features, while each has its own features, and must work under different OS architecture & file systems.  DB2 originated on mainframes, and has the longest history of enhancements there. It and DB2 LUW have longer lists of SQL statements, functions, etc, but some of this is needed due to their environment and lack of integration. Integration and automation are among the shining benefits of DB2 for i.

Comment: should go to dba.stackexchange


Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion.  The IBM midrange is a different platform than the IBM mainframe.  The midrange machine is called IBM i, or for older generations, iSeries or AS/400.  This answer is for IBM i.

DSPOBJD to a *OUTFILE.
Query columns ODUCEN and ODUDAT.

**EDIT**

If one is limted to an SQL-only solution, perhaps this will work:

```
select system_table_schema, system_table_name, lastchg from systablestats
```

**EDIT 2**

For z/OS, you probably need to make sure that [RUNSTATS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.ugref/src/tpc/db2z_utl_runstats.htm) is being run on a regular basis, then interrogate [SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACESTATS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablespacestatstable.htm) for STATSINSERTS, STATSDELETES and STATSUPDATES.

Comment: I'm the one that added the ibm-midrange tag. I added it because I don't know if there is a difference between the DB2 for i and DB2 for z/OS (I don't think there is). I also thought some of the people who are familiar with one of the platforms might be familiar with the other.

Comment: That's OK Benny.  I wasn't sure if the question needed an SQL solution or could use an OS-dependent solution.

Comment: thank you for your respones but ALTEREDTS is the time when the latest ALTER TABLE statement was applied to the table. I need sql solution.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add the version of DB2 that you are using?